# PHP - Check if value exists in array but only for specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I am checking if a value exists in the array using `in_array()`. However, I want to check only in the `ID` key and not `date`.

```
$arr = ({
    "ID":"10",
    "date":"04\/22\/20"
},
{
    "ID":"20",
    "date":"05\/25\/20"
},
{
    "ID":"32",
    "date":"07\/13\/20"
});
```

So in this example, the condition should not be met since `25` exists in `date`, but not in `ID`.

```
if (in_array("25", $arr)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Loop over the array.

Comment: Shortcut way could be passing [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) result to the `in_array()` function. Like, `in_array("25", array_column($arr, 'ID'))`. Clean, yes. Efficient, not much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly do this, you need to loop over the array.

```php
function hasId($arr, $id) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if ($value['ID'] == $id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need to do this for several IDs, it is better to convert the array to a map and use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```php
$map = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $map[$value['ID']] = $value;
    // or $map[$value['ID']] = $value['date'];
}

if (isset($map["25"])) {
    ...
}
```

This will also allow you to look up any value in the map cheaply by id using `$map[$key]`.

Answer (score 1):

For versions of PHP (>= 5.5.0), there is a simple way to do this

```
$arr = ({
    "ID":"10",
    "date":"04\/22\/20"
},
{
    "ID":"20",
    "date":"05\/25\/20"
},
{
    "ID":"32",
    "date":"07\/13\/20"
});

$searched_value = array_search('25', array_column($arr, 'ID'));
```

Here is documentation for [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it by array_filter function:

```
$searchId = '25';
$arr = [[
    "ID" => "10",
    "date" => "04\/22\/20"
],
[
    "ID" => "25",
    "date" => "05\/25\/20"
],
[
    "ID" => "32",
    "date" => "07\/13\/20"
]];

$items = array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($searchId) { 
    return $item['ID'] === $searchId;
});

if (count($items) > 0) {
   echo 'found';
};
```

Comment: This is more expensive than simply looping over the array, as it creates an entirely new array you do not need.

Comment: @AliceRyhl I have added `also` here) If just need to check the existence of the item then simple loop and return immediately would be efficient